# Spring config server cannot be disabled for local development

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was updating microservice to the newest Springboot - for now it is `2.5.5` with cloud version `2020.0.4`. However there were some changes related to connection with config server. Previously config server configuration looked like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URI:http://localhost:8888}
      fail-fast: ${CONFIG_FAIL_FAST:true}
```

However now it's required to provide it this way:

```
spring:
  config:
    import: configserver:${CONFIG_SERVER_URI:http://localhost:8888}
```

And that would be perfectly fine, except I am not able to run microservice locally without connecting to config server.
Previously I did it like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
```

And it was perfectly fine, I had separate `application-local.yaml` file and had what I wanted.
Now I tried this (according to what is said in documentation):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      import-check:
        enabled: false
      enabled: false
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888"
```

But once I run microservice locally, I get only single log like this:
`Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59759', transport: 'socket'`
And basically nothing more, seems like it keeps trying to connect to config server, because if I run config server and after this try to run my microservice, it's working fine. Additional weird thing is that IntelliJ is showing me that it doesn't recognize this `import-check` property.
As for dependencies I have only `implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:3.0.5'` related to config server.

Is there some way to run microservice locally so that it's not connecting to config server using Spring Boot 2.4+? I don't want to use bootstrapping and providing additional dependency, since there is no point to use legacy stuff.

Comment: Seems like spring context is not registering the property, I think the key for this conditional property is not being registered under a correct key, try debugging, inject the application context in one of the classes and aquire an instance of the [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) Interface, you should find it there.

Comment: I thought about it but I can't even debug it because, as I've mentioned, I don't get any logs that application is even starting. It means that I can't pretty much do anything. Even tried to set logging as TRACE, but nothing more appeared except what I provided. That's really weird.

Comment: How did you configure you IDE to use `application-local.yaml` to start Springboot instead of default config ? I use similar configs.. for local and non-local but with spring profiles and all the configs are in `application.yaml` file

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and in that case once you create your Run/Debug configuration, inside tab "Configuration", in "Spring Boot" section you have text field called "Active profiles" where you can provide multiple profiles that you want. Thanks to this you can have multiple property files with proper suffixes like "application-local.yml", "application-dev.yml" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the configuration I have for `application.yaml` in `/src/main/resources` folder.

```
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: "!config-local"
    import: configserver:http://config-server.example.com:8888/
  cloud:
    config.fail-fast: true
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: "config-local"
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888/
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
```

And in Intellij IDEA Run config, I set the active Profile as `config-local` this works with Springboot `2.5.5` and

```
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.4")
}
```

Comment: Actually this is a nice workaround to this which worked for me by using this `activate.on-profile` property, thanks!